# sql consulta con doble rango usando between

Tags: sql-server

El departamento de recursos humanos necesita un informe que muestre el apellido y la fecha de contratación de todos los empleados contratados en 1995 o 2005.

como hago eso si el dato de la fecha es tipo datetime y el rango que me pide solo es el año?

Comment: DATEPART(Year, Date_Column) BETWEEN tu_date1 AND tu_date2

Comment: Sin saber la estructura de tus tablas, lo que vas a recibir son respuestas genéricas. Por favor, concreta más tu pregunta y añade toda la información necesaria

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT APELLIDO, FECHA_CONTRATO
FROM EMPLEADOS
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,COLUMNA) IN (Año1,Año2)
```

Algo así te puede ayudar. !

Comment: En la consulta pusieron 1995 o 2005, Despues hablo de rango, No se especifico bien. de Igual manera Cambiamos el IN por BETWEEN y los años para el Rango.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he usado esto algunas veces y siempre me ha funcionado bien:

```
"SELECT * FROM $dbTable WHERE date(fecha) BETWEEN 'fecha1' AND 'fecha2' ORDER BY fecha DESC"
```